# Python - Trying to send a request to Codeforces

Tags: python-3.x, http

I am pretty new to sending requests and stuff like that and I try a simple exercise where I connect to codeforces and get a response:

https://codeforces.com/api/help this is the help link which explains it - but I really dont get it

```
contestId=556
secret="secretkey"
apiKey="apikey"
timeValue = time.time()
rand = random.randint(000000,999999)
hashCode = hashlib.sha512()
hashCode.update(str(""+str(rand)+"/contest.list?apiKey="+apiKey+"&contestId="+str(contestId)+"&time="+str(timeValue)+"#"+secret).encode())
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("http://codeforces.com/api")
conn.request("GET","/contest.list?contestId="+str(contestId)+"&apiKey="+str(apiKey)+"&time="+str(timeValue)+"apiSig="+str(rand)+str(hashCode.digest()))
res = conn.getresponse()
print(res.status, res.reason)
```

what do I have to change in my code so it works? Any help would be appreciated, already read through the python documentation of HTTP.Client ... but well...